# How to compare pandas data frames and then "fill in" any missing rows with the other data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following two arrays: Data and Baseline

```
Data
   Phase  ENSO  EJO
0      1    -1    2
1      1     0    2
2      1     1    2
3      2    -1    7
4      2     1    1

Baseline
   Phase  ENSO  EJO
0      1    -1    0.0
1      1     0    0.0
2      1     1    0.0
3      2    -1    0.0
4      2     0    0.0
5      2     1    0.0
```

I want to alter the 'Data' data frame such that the "missing row" gets filled in by the Baseline data. Final result would look like this

```
Data
   Phase  ENSO  EJO
0      1    -1    2
1      1     0    2
2      1     1    2
3      2    -1    7
4      2     0    0
5      2     1    1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `reindex` `Data` by `Baseline` indices and fill the missing values with `Baseline` values using `fillna`.

```
Data = Data.reindex(Baseline.index).fillna(Baseline)
```

Another option is to use `combine_first`:

```
Data = Data.combine_first(Baseline)
```

Output:

```
   Phase  ENSO  EJO
0    1.0  -1.0  2.0
1    1.0   0.0  2.0
2    1.0   1.0  2.0
3    2.0  -1.0  7.0
4    2.0   1.0  1.0
5    2.0   1.0  0.0
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for. On index 4 I want it to be 2 0 0 and index 5 to be 2 1 1

Comment: @Jack can you explain the logic for that? It doesn't seem to make any sense....

Comment: @richardec I'm eventually going to use these values to form a grid such that each each phase (1-8) has a corresponding ENSO number (-1, 0, and 1), but since I created my 'data' data frame using a count function, sometimes a ENSO-phase combination (in our case that's a 2 from phase matched with a 0 from ENSO) does not exist. Which is why I need baseline to fill that in

Answer (score 0):

[enke's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71042209/17242583) is great - here's a solution that preserves the original datatypes:

```
Data = pd.concat([Data, Baseline[~Baseline.index.isin(Data.index)]])
```

Output:

```
>>> Data
   Phase  ENSO  EJO
0      1    -1  2.0
1      1     0  2.0
2      1     1  2.0
3      2    -1  7.0
4      2     1  1.0
5      2     1  0.0
```

Comment: The indices of column 4 and 5 aren't exactly what I laid out in my desired Output

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ultra-short solution:

```
>>> tmp = baseline.copy()
>>> tmp.update(data)
>>> tmp
   Phase  ENSO  EJO
0    1.0  -1.0  2.0
1    1.0   0.0  2.0
2    1.0   1.0  2.0
3    2.0  -1.0  7.0
4    2.0   1.0  1.0
5    2.0   1.0  0.0
```

Or (Python 3.8+)

```
>>> (tmp := baseline.copy()).update(data)
>>> tmp
   Phase  ENSO  EJO
0    1.0  -1.0  2.0
1    1.0   0.0  2.0
2    1.0   1.0  2.0
3    2.0  -1.0  7.0
4    2.0   1.0  1.0
5    2.0   1.0  0.0
```

Simplest:

```
>>> baseline.update(data)
>>> baseline
   Phase  ENSO  EJO
0    1.0  -1.0  2.0
1    1.0   0.0  2.0
2    1.0   1.0  2.0
3    2.0  -1.0  7.0
4    2.0   1.0  1.0
5    2.0   1.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the assumption that you want to decide which rows need to be filled based on the values of `Phase` and `ENSO` columns. Here is my solution based on that.

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

x_str = """Phase  ENSO  EJO
0      1    -1    2
1      1     0    2
2      1     1    2
3      2    -1    7
4      2     1    1"""

y_str = """Phase  ENSO  EJO
0      1    -1    0.0
1      1     0    0.0
2      1     1    0.0
3      2    -1    0.0
4      2     0    0.0
5      2     1    0.0"""

x = pd.read_csv(StringIO(x_str), sep="\s+")
y = pd.read_csv(StringIO(y_str), sep="\s+")

# Outer merge with indicator on
z = pd.merge(x, y, how='outer', on=['Phase', 'ENSO'], indicator=True)
rows_to_be_filled = z['_merge'].isin(['right_only'])
z.loc[rows_to_be_filled, 'EJO_x'] = z.loc[rows_to_be_filled, 'EJO_y']

# Cleanup
z = z.rename({'EJO_x': 'EJO'}, axis=1).drop(['EJO_y', '_merge'], axis=1)
z
#    Phase  ENSO  EJO
# 0      1    -1  2.0
# 1      1     0  2.0
# 2      1     1  2.0
# 3      2    -1  7.0
# 4      2     1  1.0
# 5      2     0  0.0
```